# NoSuchMethodException with getter and setter in play framework 1.2.5, when deployed in weblogic

Tags: playframework-1.x, nosuchmethoderror

I am using play framework for my application. It workks correctly in dev mode but gives me an error in prod mode

```
Execution exception (In /app/helper/FinansHelper.java around line 189)
NoSuchMethodException occured : finansServis.helper.KayitliIslemDto.getIpcMemo()
```

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: My KayitliIslemDto class

```
public class KayitliIslemDto {
    public IPCMemo ipcMemo;
    public TahsilatMemoOut tahsilatMemoOut;
    public HesabaHavaleMemoOut hesabaHavaleMemoOut;
    public IsmeHavaleMemoOut ismeHavaleMemoOut;

    public KayitliIslemDto(IPCMemo ipcMemo, IsmeHavaleMemoOut ismeHavaleMemoOut) {
        this.ipcMemo = ipcMemo;
        this.ismeHavaleMemoOut = ismeHavaleMemoOut;
    }

    public KayitliIslemDto(IPCMemo ipcMemo, HesabaHavaleMemoOut hesabaHavaleMemoOut) {
        this.ipcMemo = ipcMemo;
        this.hesabaHavaleMemoOut = hesabaHavaleMemoOut;
    }

    public KayitliIslemDto(IPCMemo ipcMemo, TahsilatMemoOut tahsilatMemoOut) {
        this.ipcMemo = ipcMemo;
        this.tahsilatMemoOut = tahsilatMemoOut;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post you `KayitliIslemDto` object?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Play Framework. It might highly possible that your JVM locale is Turkish. 'I' in method names are sometimes converted to 'İ' by the JVM that you use.

I solved the problem by setting up JVM system parameters:

```
play run ExampleProject -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=TR -Duser.variant=TR
```

I hope it works for you, too.